# Difference between the what do you study&what are you studying

Tags: difference

I want to know the difference between:

> - What do you study?
> - What are you studying?

I am a English learner I learn English through apps. Recently I read a question “What do you study?” up to now I know only “What are you studying?"

Answer (score 3):

> What do you study?

The simple present implies an activity pursued over a long timespan: it would typically be used to ask someone what curriculum or topic of study they are engaged in when they are studying. They need not be actually studying at the moment of asking.

> What are you studying?

The progressive may have the same meaning, but it may also imply immediate activity: what are you doing *right now*, what is the subject of the textbook I see in front of you or the essay I see you writing?